# First function gets stuck in async.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I tried to execute a series of events in my Node.js project with [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) as follows:

**server.js:**

```
var express = require('express');
var async = require('async');

...

app.get('/my_page', function (req, res) {
    async.series([
        function() { console.log("calling foo()"); },
        function() { foo(); },
        function() { console.log("foo() done"); },
    ]);
    res.render('my_page', {});
}
```

but I only get the first console output and it's stuck.. the `function()`s were `function(callback)`s before. I thought it was waiting a value to be returned but removing them doesn't change the situation..

What am I doing wrong? (I'm newbie to Node.js)

Thanks for any help,

Comment: Well, none of these three functions is asynchronous or takes and calls a callback, so I wonder why you are using `async.js` at all?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the documentation. Each function should get `callback` as a parameter, and should call `callback` once it's done, thus telling `async` it's time to move on to the next function. So you should have something like:

```
function(callback) { 
    console.log("calling foo()"); 
    callback();
},
```

If there was an error in one of the functions, call `callback` with the error as the 1st parameter. If you want `res.render('my_page', {});` to be executed only after the last function is executed, wrap it in a function and put it as the 2nd parameter to `async.series`.

And of course, if non of the functions is asynchronous, you should consider not using `async`.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I'm not sure why you're using async here, since none of the functions you've provided to the `async.series` function are asynchronous.

async.series is useful for calling multiple asynchronous functions in a row and avoiding [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/).

```
var async = require("async");

function asyncA(callback){
  // do something
  callback(null, "value-a");
}

function asyncB(callback){
  // do something else
  callback(null, "value-b");
}

asyncA(function(err, valueA){
  console.log(valueA); // "value-a"
  asyncB(function(err, valueB){
    console.log(valueB); // "value-b"
  });
});


async.series([asyncA, asyncB], function(err, results){
  console.log(results); // ["value-a", "value-b"]
}
```

I suggest doing some reading on asynchronous functions and callbacks and consider whether you really need the `async` library. I recommend the [You Don't Know JS chapter on asynchronous javascript](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/async%20%26%20performance/ch1.md) and the series as a whole :)